# Как экспортировать функцию под видом класса?

Tags: наследование, typescript, конструктор

Хочу сделать класс на основе массива с добавленным методом `get`, который реализует циклическое обращение. Изначально код выглядел так:

```
export class CircularArray extends Array<string> {
    constructor(data: string[]) {
        super();
        this.push(...data);
    }

    get(i: number): string {
        return this[i % this.length];
    }
}
```

И в тайпскрипте версии 2.0.10 всё работало. Однако, когда я решил обновить тайпскрипт до актуальной версии 2.2.0, оказалось, что код стал компилироваться [по-другому](//www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20CircularArray%20extends%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.push(...data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(i%3A%20number)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%5Bi%20%25%20this.length%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A), а именно, в конструкторе появилась обработка возвращаемого из вызова `super()` значения:

```
function CircularArray(data) {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
    _this.push.apply(_this, data);
    return _this;
}
```

Это приводит к тому, что возвращается объект, созданный при вызове `Array()`. Естественно, его прототип - `Array.prototype`, а не `CircularArray.prototype`, поэтому мой метод `get` теряется. Как решить эту проблему?

Пытаюсь сделать нечто такое:

```
export declare class CircularArray extends Array<string> {
    constructor(data: string[]);
    get(i: number): string;
}

export function CircularArray(data: string[]): CircularArray {
    this.push(...data);
    return this;
};

CircularArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

CircularArray.prototype.get = function (i: number): string {
    return this[i % this.length];
};
```

Но получаю логичный комплект ошибок:

> error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CircularArray'.
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CircularArray'.

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски](//stackoverflow.com/q/42345028/4928642)

Comment: Ну так и не пиши, что у тебя функция возвращает _CircularArray_, если она ничего не возвращает :)

Comment: @Grundy, это я уже исправил. Основная проблема - что получается `Duplicate identifier` из-за функции и объявления класса. Не знаю, как переписать, чтобы в других местах нормально использовать можно было.

Comment: так это, а обязательно в обоих местах экспорт делать?

Comment: @Grundy, так ошибка от экспорта не зависит... И вроде бы обязательно?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42345028/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл способ:

```
export interface CircularArray extends Array<string> {
    constructor(data: string[]): CircularArray;
    get(i: number): string;
}

export var CircularArray: { new (data: string[]): CircularArray } = function CircularArray(data: string[]): void {
    this.push(...data);
} as any;

CircularArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

CircularArray.prototype.get = function (i: number): string {
    return this[i % this.length];
};
```